# Mysql query where column_name=a the same as column_name=0?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, get

When i am running a query, for example:

> "SELECT * FROM program_detaljer where program_ref_id='a'"

All I get from the result is program_ref_id = 0.

Why does this happen, when the program_ref_id column is supposed to be int(11)?

Comment: so program_ref_id column is an INT and you are comparing it with a character in your query?

Comment: I compared it with an character by a mistake, and got an error on my site. Solved it with an prepared statement, and got curious why this happend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about [types conversion in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html)

Before comparison mysql tries to convert string ('a') to number ('0').

```
mysql> SELECT 0='a';
+-------+
| 0='a' |
+-------+
|     1 |
+-------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

You could check value before quering. Or replace `=` with `LIKE` : ). (But better to check value type before.)

```
mysql> SELECT 0 LIKE 'a';
+------------+
| 0 LIKE 'a' |
+------------+
|          0 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```